# Select associated records based on comparison with array column

Tags: sql, postgresql

Suppose a hypothetical scenario with following tables

```
Vehicles
+----+--------+
| id | number |
+----+--------+
|  1 | v1     |
|  2 | v2     |
|  3 | v3     |
+----+--------+

Users
+-----+------+-------------+
| id  | name | vehicle_ids |
+-----+------+-------------+
| 100 | u1   | {1}         |
| 200 | u2   | {1,2}       |
| 300 | u3   | {2,3}       |
| 400 | u4   | {}          |
+-----+------+-------------+
```

Given `number` of a vehicle I am looking for a query that returns all the users associated with that vehicle,

1. where vehicle_ids contains the id of vehicle
2. where vehicle_ids only has the id of vehicle (i.e single element)

Answer (score 1):

We can use `ANY` and `ALL` constructs (more details here  [Row and Array Comparisons](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-comparisons.html))

## USING "ANY"

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/ec886/21

For first case where we need to return users that are associated with vehicle represented by search query (along with others) we can use ANY. So, following query will return user rows with name `u2` and `u3` when supplied with `v2` as vehicle name

```
SELECT "users".* 
FROM "users" 
WHERE (
  (SELECT "vehicles"."id" FROM "vehicles" WHERE "vehicles"."number" = 'v2') = 
ANY("users"."vehicle_ids")
)
```

You can replace `"number" = 'v2'` with any other vehicle name to get all the users which are associated with this vehicle number.

## USING "ALL"

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/ec886/27

For second case where we need exact match i.e. only one element in the array, we will use All. So following query will return only user row with name `u1` when `v1`

```
SELECT "users".* 
FROM "users" 
WHERE (
  "users"."vehicle_ids" != '{}' and
  (SELECT "vehicles"."id" FROM "vehicles" WHERE "vehicles"."number" = 'v1') = ALL("users"."vehicle_ids")
)
```

If we don't use `"users"."vehicle_ids" != '{}'` then the result will also contain user `u4`

## Note:

This subquery method will only work for single vehicle i.e. we can't do `WHERE "vehicles"."number" in ('v2', v3)` as the subquery will return multiple rows and Postgres will throw an error. We might have to explore `unnest` if it can serve the same purpose as original question and also if it is generic enough to support aforementioned use case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `unnest()` as well:

```
select u.*
from users u cross join lateral
     unnest(vehicle_ids) x(vehicle_id) join
     vehicles v
     on v.id = x.vehicle_id
where v.number = 'v2';
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=1eeb8da0f63968b498444386349e69ff) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: +1 the answer I provided mentions exploring unnest to achieve the same result as I felt it could be done but I was lazy enough to not do it. So thank you for adding it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Question #1: "where vehicle_ids contains the id of vehicle"

You can join the two tables with a condition on the array

```sql
select u.*
from users u
  join vehicles v on v.id = any(u.vehicle_ids)
where v.number = 'v1';
```

Question #2: "where vehicle_ids only has the id of vehicle (i.e single element)"

This can be achieved by create a single element array from a SELECT statement

```
select u.*
from users u
where u.vehicle_ids = array(select v.id from vehicle v where v.number = 'v1');
```

Comment: That array wrapping  (and then = comparison) is definitely something new I learned .